# Tensorflow input for a series of (1, 512) tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow, shapes, word-embedding, bert-language-model

I have a pandas dataset with a column of tensors of shape `TensorShape([1, 512])` which are a result of `tf.hub` Bert embeddings. I know I can use an embedding layer directly in tensorflow, but is there a way to feed the data as it is in the Input layer?

I've tried with a (1, 512) shape input layer but I have an error: `"Failed to convert a Numpy array to a Tensor"`. I've tried to feed it as a `np.array` instead of a series, but it's not working...

I would guess that it's a shape problem, but I don't see how to solve it!

Edits : I used USE from `tf.hub` : https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-large/5

Comment: It's hard to diagnose without your code, but can't you freeze the BERT model (set the weights as non trainable), and pass the output node directly as an input in your model?

Comment: @Lescurel I'll edit it to add some code! It's my first question so it might take some time to me to figure it out! :D

Comment: Can you please add the error message you are getting along with some code to understand the issue.